# R googlesheets4 pass token as parameter to read_sheet

Tags: r, google-sheets, token, googlesheets4

I can read a sheet only if the sheet is already authorised,

If not, every subsequent line of code is ignored, as the code execution keeps asking for the token. Is there a way to pass the token index into the read_sheet command, or some way to authorise access beforehand?

```
   > aa <- read_sheet('https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d....', sheet='Akinesia', range="AC:AH")
The googlesheets4 package is requesting access to your Google account. Select a pre-authorised account or enter '0' to obtain a new token. Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort.

1: chris.elliott@.....

Selection: 
Enter an item from the menu, or 0 to exit
Selection: 
Enter an item from the menu, or 0 to exit
Selection: 
Enter an item from the menu, or 0 to exit
Selection: aaX <- aa  %>% filter_all(any_vars(!is.na(.)))
Enter an item from the menu, or 0 to exit
Selection: akns <- aaX %>% pivot_longer(-genotype, names_to = "day", values_to = "nonresp")
Enter an item from the menu, or 0 to exit
```

Answer (score 0):

You need to make an auth call which provides different authentication methods:

### default auth

Try default call without params or with email address that is associated with a Google account:

```r
googlesheets4::gs4_auth(email = "chris.elliott@...")
```

### service account

you can also pass token file associated with a service account:

```r
googlesheets4::gs4_auth(path = "access_token.json")
```

> path - JSON identifying the service account, in one of the forms supported for the txt argument of jsonlite::fromJSON() (typically, a file path or JSON string).

### gargle token

`googlesheets4` uses [gargle](https://github.com/r-lib/gargle) package, so you should be able also to get the token like this:

```r
library(gargle)
token <- token_fetch()
googlesheets4::gs4_auth(token = token)
```

Comment: Sorry, these don't help. default auth and service account both sent back the message

```The googlesheets4 package is requesting access to your Google account. Select a pre-authorised account or enter '0' to obtain a new token. Press Esc/Ctrl + C to abort.```

This doesn't help get the saved token automatically, 

gargle token code just started the Google password dialog.

I really wanted to be able to automatically select the men item No1

Comment: Try the first option with email parameter set explicitly

Answer (score 0):

I think the option that @Bulat suggested works, i.e., using the email address associated with your Google account directly within the `gs4_auth()` call.